# What i need to give in the chat room search box to get the r chatroom at first?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to get into r chatroom. If i type r in the chat room search box, it lists all the chatrooms which has the character r in their chatroom description or in their names. But i want the chatroom which has the name r only to be at the top of the list.

[image]
 <sub>In regex i could do this through `^r$`</sub> :)

Comment: Try searching for "r public" instead.  This is in no way a general solution, but it will find the R chat rooms.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg it works, but a general solution would be better.

Comment: It works because you'll find references to "r public" in the "r" chat room.  You probably also want "r public" instead of "r".  I don't know of a general solution; perhaps someone will come along and give a proper answer to your question.

Comment: [Relevant (?) chat conversation related to allowing use of regex in web data queries.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18379645#18379645)